# using phonegap with gwt in IntelliJ

Tags: gwt, cordova, intellij-idea

I want to migrate all my project to one source code using GWT.
The wen is using GWT and using RPC to GAE.

I'm looking for a phonegap-gwt-intelliJ sample project. Something that I can start with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yo

http://funfreelance.com/android-using-intellij-ide-with-phonegap/

enjoy :)

Well, i've done today an Hello World APP with Eclipse/PhoneGap and, as i use to code with PhpStorm ,i found Eclipse not so well and complicated to implement simple things ....(not as fast , complicated way to add simple javascript Autocompletion, you have to add HTML view , PHP view and so one) .... witch IDE are you using (for the people that read this post ) .....